# radio button extends to dropdown for more option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have few radio buttons for selecting common choices and the rest goes into a dropdown called others. So the user can select only one option either from the dropdown or radio button. After selecting one option the rest will disappear(already implemented). What i cant figure out is how to make the dropdown work as a part of radiobutton??

html:

```
<form>
  <group class="inline-radio">

    <div>
      <input id="opt1" type="radio" name="title">
      <label>opt1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="opt2" type="radio" name="title">
      <label>opt2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="opt3" type="radio" name="title">
      <label>opt3</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="opt4" type="radio" name="title">
      <label>opt4</label>
    </div>

    <!-- DropDown -->
    <div class="dropdown drop-hide">
      <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
        Others
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </button>
      <ul style="clear:both" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- DropDown End-->

  </group>
  <span class="tip">Please choose one</span>

</form>
```

javascript:

```
  //for toggling  
    var hid = false;

    $("group.inline-radio").click(function() {
      if (hid == false) {

        $('group.inline-radio').find('input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').parent().hide().find('label').hide();
       hid = true;
        return;
      } else {
        $('group.inline-radio').find('input[type="radio"]').not(':checked').parent().show().find('label').show();

        hid = false;
      }

    });


    $("input:radio[name=title]").click(function() {

      var id = $(this).attr('id');
      var value;
      var value;
      $("input:radio[name=title]")
      switch (id) {
        case "opt1":
          value = "opt1";
          break;
        case "opt2":
          value = "opt2";
          break;
        case "opt3":
          value = "opt3";
          break;
        case "opt4":
          value = "opt4";
          break;
        case "opt5":
          value = "opt5";
          break;
        case "opt6":
          value = "opt6";
          break;
        case "opt7":
          value = "opt7";
          break;

        default:
          value = "Please choose an option";
      }
      $("span.tip").text(value);

    });

    //for dropdown

    $(function() {

      $(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function() {

        $(".btn:first-child").text($(this).text());
        $(".btn:first-child").val($(this).text());

      });

    });
```

For a clearer picture here is the project in codepen.
http://codepen.io/flyingboy007/pen/wKpWoY

Comment: not clear what you want to do

Comment: @imGaurav Want the dropdown to work along with the radio buttons..(like extended radio buttons).means the user can either click a radio button or an item in dropdown

Comment: Perhaps you want a `<select>` dropdown instead of a menu dropdown? Do you want the values of "dropdown" to apply to "radio", and vice versa? Check out [Bootstrap selects](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#selects)

Comment: see my answer may be  it will solve your problem event it is  printing value also

Comment: @turbopipp yes exactly..

Comment: @ABHILASHV.R I tried to make a solution below, it uses a select dropdown instead of a menu dropdown. Menu dropdowns are not designed to change values, but select dropdowns are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this example : http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/7ntgay11/2/

**Updated answer now radio button is checked also when you select value from droup down http://jsfiddle.net/kevalbhatt18/7ntgay11/**

i removed button tag and i am using input and type="radio" may be it will help you

```
<div class="dropdown drop-hide">
  <input id="opt5" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="radio" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" name="title">
      <label>opt5</label>
  <ul style="clear:both" class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. the updated one is not what i wanted as its not unselecting other radios. The problem now is that how can i change the label based on the the list selected.Also i only want to make the hide effect work on selecting a option from the others tab..Please have a look at this  http://codepen.io/flyingboy007/pen/wKpWoY

Comment: @ABHILASHV.R it is unselecting other radio button  after selecting option from droup down k will edit my fiddle

Comment: Thank you..but can u tell me how to change the name opt5 to the one that got selected?

Comment: @ABHILASHV.R Happy to help you :D

Answer (score 0):

It seems you might want to change from a menu dropdown to a select dropdown.

[jsfiddle working example](http://jsfiddle.net/turbopipp/nrf7oohr/)

```js
$(function() {
    var radio = $(".inline-radio input[name='title']");
    var select = $(".inline-radio select");
    var tip = $("span.tip");
    select.on('change', function() {
        var option = $(this).find(":selected").text();
        $('#' + option).prop('checked',true);
        tip.text(option);
    });
    radio.on('change', function() {
        var option = $(this).attr('id');
        select.val(option);
        tip.text(option);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <group class="inline-radio">
    <div>
      <input id="opt1" type="radio" name="title" checked="checked" />
      <label>opt1</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="opt2" type="radio" name="title" />
      <label>opt2</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="opt3" type="radio" name="title" />
      <label>opt3</label>
    </div>

    <select class="form-control">
      <option>opt1</option>
      <option>opt2</option>
      <option>opt3</option>
    </select>

  </group>
  <span class="tip">Please choose one</span>

</form>
```

Comment: Its slightly different behaviour than i expect @kevalbhatt answer is the one i am after.. Thanks for trying to help